# How to retrieve a String value from Serial.read();

Tags: c, arrays, string, arduino, arduino-ide

I am trying to send an SMS that contains multiple values as a String, which then will be received by the Arduino board as a Serial.read(); command. For example, if i where to send the following SMS to the board, "Username PhoneNumber Email". The code will then receive the SMS and divides it into different String values, which i can then use in the code.

So far i have been able to do all of that, the issue that i am currently facing, is that i can seem to receive the text message as a String value, which means that the board is not receiving it as a String, instead it is receiving it as char[].

in result, i am getting the following output when i try to print out the value,

```
> 1: U
2: 
3: 
1: s
2: 
3: 
1: e
2: 
3: 
1: r
2: 
3: 
1: n
2: 
3: 
1: ame
2: PhoneNu
3: 
1: mber
2: Email
3:
```

what i want is to get this output,

```
1:UserName 
2:PhoneNumber 
3:Email
```

The following is the code i am using:

```
void setup()
{ 
  Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop()
{
  if(Serial.available()>0)
  {
char string[100];
char byteRead;

int availableBytes = Serial.available();
for(int i=0; i<availableBytes; i++)
{
    string[i] = Serial.read();
    string[i+1] = '\0'; // Append a null
} 

String dj = string;
  //char inchar=Serial.read();
  String split= dj;
  String word1 = getValue(split, ' ', 0);
  Serial.println("1: "+word1);
  String word2 = getValue(split, ' ', 1);
  Serial.println("2: "+word2);
  String word3 = getValue(split, ' ', 2);
  Serial.println("3: "+word3);
  }
}
 String getValue(String data, char separator, int index)
{
  int found = 0;
  int strIndex[] = {0, -1};
  int maxIndex = data.length()-1;

  for(int i=0; i<=maxIndex && found<=index; i++){
    if(data.charAt(i)==separator || i==maxIndex){
        found++;
        strIndex[0] = strIndex[1]+1;
        strIndex[1] = (i == maxIndex) ? i+1 : i;
    }
  }

  return found>index ? data.substring(strIndex[0], strIndex[1]) : "";
}
```

I want the userName to go into String 1, PhoneNumber into String 2 and Email into String 3.

Thank you!! :D

Comment: look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697047/convert-serial-read-into-a-useable-string-using-arduino

Answer (score 1):

Your code assumes/requires that all of the data is already available on the serial port when you call `loop()`. Probably it is not.

From the code that you posted it seems that you must be calling the `loop()` function repetitively. This, combined with the possibility that only a small amount of the data is actually available at each read, results in the output that you show.

Is there a termination character (e.g. new line) that you can use to determine the end of an SMS record? Can you add one? If so then you may be able to use [readBytesUntil()](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/ReadBytesUntil) to read input from the serial port until you see the terminator (or a timeout or buffer filled). You might need to call this a few times to accumulate the full SMS record before parsing it in `getValue()`