# Received String Data From Android Apps Blutooh (Bluetooth Terminal) to Arduino using Bluetooth HC-05

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, communication

I want to create a system that can send messages between android app with arduino using bluetooth module. I Used bluetooth terminal (android) made by qwerty

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX
String Data = "";

void setup()  
{
    mySerial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() // run over and over
{
  while(mySerial.available()==0)
  {}

  char character;
  while(mySerial.available()>0)
  {
    character = mySerial.read();
    mySerial.write(character);
  }

  data = data + character;

  if (character == 13) {  
    mySerial.print("Received: ");
    mySerial.println(data);
    data = "";
  } 
}
```

Everything it's ok when I send single character, but if I send string data (more than 1 character) arduino can't received it correctly.  always error data in second character received.

Anyone can describe and help me to solve the problem?
Any response are appreciated.

If solved the problem, I will posted the guide.

Comment: example, if i type test, arduino only display tyyy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX
String Data = "";

void setup() {
    mySerial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() // run over and over
{
  while(mySerial.available()==0)
  {}

  char character;
  while(mySerial.available()>0)
  {
    character = mySerial.read();
    mySerial.write(character);
    data = data + character;
  }

 // data = data + character;

  if (character == 13) {  
    mySerial.print("Received: ");
    mySerial.println(data);
    data = "";`enter code here`
  } 
}
```

Comment: what does character==13 mean?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get more than one character, use arrays to store all the characters from the buffer at once.

May be this will give you some idea.

[this post does it nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697047/convert-serial-read-into-a-useable-string-using-arduino)

Comment: Hy CCR. Thanjs you.. 
I have try that's tutorial, its worked if using terminal. But if I used Bluetooth communication (using android phone) I confused to implement the code. 
Any solution or sample using Bluetooth communication?